# Several CSS files for 11ty with Nunjucks

Tags: html, css, nunjucks, eleventy

So I have an 11ty site structured like this

```
.
└── app/
    ├── public
    ├── src /
    │   ├── _includes/
    │   │   ├── base.njk
    │   │   ├── header.njk
    │   │   └── footer.njk
    │   ├── css/
    │   │   ├── about.css
    │   │   ├── contact.css
    │   │   ├── core.style.css
    │   │   ├── index.css
    │   ├── images
    │   ├── about.njk
    │   ├── contact.njk
    │   ├── index.njk
```

And base.njk file for styling the layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.style.css" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'header.njk' %}
    {{ content | safe }}
    {% include 'footer.njk' %}
</body>
</html>
```

With this, I can style all njk files:

index.njk

```html
---
title: My App - Homepage
layout: base.njk
---

<div class="container">
    <img
        src="/images/image.png"
    />
</div>
```

So far, everything is working. My question is there is a way I can use different CSS files to style each njk file, eg: about.css for about.njk? Right now, I can style all njk files under one file which is base.njk.

Comment: you could make a block in the <head> of base.njk and when you extend it i.e on about.njk you put the about.css in the block etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods to achieve this with different advantages and drawbacks.

### Page Variables

The simplest way would probably be to set the path to the CSS file in your front matter. This method is fairly flexible and works well.

```html
---
title: About
layout: base.njk
cssFile: "about.css"
---
<!-- ... -->
```

```html
<!-- base.njk -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ cssFile }}" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <!-- ... -->
```

### Automatic Linking From Filename

If you know for sure that there is a CSS file for every page, and that the filenames match, you can find the CSS file automatically based on the template name using the [`page` variable](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/#page-variable). However, this may cause issues if there isn't a CSS file for that page or your filenames become out of sync.

```html
<!-- base.njk -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css{{ page.filePathStem }}.css" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <!-- ... -->
```

### Blocks

The most flexible way to achieve this is by using [Nunjucks blocks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#block). However, blocks cannot be used with Eleventy layouts, so layouts must be defined through Nunjucks by `extend`ing another template.

Create a block in the `<head>` of `base.njk`.

```html
<!-- base.njk -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.style.css" />
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Then in your `about.njk`, inject your `<link>` tag into the `head` block. Use `{% extends "item.html" %}` instead of layout.

```html
---
title: About
---
{% extends "base.njk" %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Great answer, really useful! How would you go about going through a similar process for your 'Page Variables' answer but to inject the specific css file as an inline style tag to load before non-critical linked css files?